signer.sendTransaction is not a function
Iam trying token transfer to a wallet address using ether.js. I followed official docs but still getting the above error. Where Iam wrong.
const startPayment = async ({ setError, setTxs, ether, addr }) => {
  try {
    if (!window.ethereum) throw new Error('No crypto wallet found. Please install it.');

    await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    // Validate the address
    const validatedAddr = ethers.getAddress(addr);

    console.log("this",signer);
    
    const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
      to: validatedAddr,
      value: ethers.parseEther(ether),
    });

    const receipt = await tx.wait();

    console.log({ ether, addr });
    console.log('tx', receipt);
    setTxs([receipt]);
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err.message);
  }
};

It is expected to send the transaction but it is not identifying the function.
